# generator backfire

Tags: gas, generator

my generator has 12HP Honda . It sat all winter . Started up first pull last year, this year pulled and cleaned plug after it would not start .  Pulled cord, had a  backfire and did not start? Had stabilizer in gas and added hydrate,let it sit, nothing

Comment: I see a presentation of the situation, but no clear question that matches the title.  Can you expand on this one a bit?  What model is it?  Does it use two-stroke fuel?  Things like that.

Comment: Did you drain the carburetor or close the fuel valve and run until it died last use?  Are you using fresh fuel?  Wasnlast years gas premium without ethanol, or regular unleaded with ethanol?